# Signed document that is returned from DocuSign to our application is missing a signature

Tags: docusignapi

Our application is able to use DocuSign REST API to create an envelope for users to sign, and return the signed document to our application once the signing is done.

**Recently**, the issue is when the document signing has been completed, it is always missing the last signature. For example, we have indicated 3 signers to sign, but in the completed document it only shows 2 signatures.

The missing signature problem only happens to the completed document that is pushed back to our application. When the signers receive the signed document via DocuSign's email, all 3 signature are in the attached signed document.

Please let us know if there is any change to any API recently that cause us to face this issue, or what configuration do we need to fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You say that your DocuSign "return[s] the signed document to our application"

If you're using Connect or the eventNotifications attribute for this, then you're using the DocuSign webhook system. Check that the webhook events you're interested in **only** list `Envelope Complete`. Not `Recipient Complete`.

Also check if the status of the envelope itself is `complete`. You've not indicated whether the problem is that the last signer is not asked to sign or if you're receiving a notification before the last signer signs.

If you're using a template, check that the template has not been changed and works as expected when it is sent from the DocuSign web app (vs the API).

### Added

In the comments, the OP notes that they:

- are using Connect webhooks
- are requesting notifications for both `Recipient Complete` and `Envelope Complete`

In addition, from the question, I believe that the developer is using the default `Aggregate` queuing method.

#### What's happening

When `aggregate` queuing is used, notifications are initiated when a requested event occurs. But if a second requested event occurs before the notification from the first event is sent, only one notification will be sent for both events, and the notification content will reflect the later (the second) event.

So what is usually happening:

1. The last recipient signs (completes)
2. The `recipient complete` event triggers a notification. It is not yet sent.
3. The envelope as a whole becomes complete milliseconds after item 1.
4. The `envelope complete` event is triggered. The `recipient complete` notification has not yet been sent.
5. The notification is actually sent. The notification includes the envelope complete information.

What will sometimes happen:

1. The last recipient signs (completes)
2. The `recipient complete` event triggers a notification.
3. The DocuSign system sends off the notification. It shows that the recipient is complete but not the envelope.
4. The envelope as a whole becomes complete.
5. The `envelope complete` event is triggered.
6. The notification is sent. The notification includes the envelope complete information.

### Conclusions

If you are only interested in the `envelope complete` status (everyone signed) then **do not** request the `recipient complete` events!

If you want `recipient complete` and also want `envelope complete` events, then your application needs to inspect the incoming notification to determine the envelope's status.

### Added re why not `recipient_complete`?

`recipient_complete` events should only be requested if your application will take action as each recipient in the envelope completes. (A signer is complete when they sign, a cc recipient is complete when the email has been sent to them, etc.)

If your app will only take action when the envelope as a whole is complete, then asking for recipient_complete events too will only cause additional notifications that can be confusing to your app's logic.

Comment: Hi Larry, in our DocuSign Connect, we have enabled both Envelope Complete and Recipient Complete. [https://www.dropbox.com/s/8yo6zptzfwsobmk/Docusign%20Connect%20settings.png?dl=0] . This is part of the code about the events that we listen to: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/zo2p6mezxat9i0b/Event.png?dl=0]

In our setup, we have indicated that every signer must sign, logged in to each signer's email to click the DocuSign link to sign the document. We only receive a notification after the last signer signs. After this, when opening the document in our application, the last signature is missing.

Comment: May I know also understand why do you advise to only enable "Envelope Complete" and not "Recipient Complete"?